# You could open a chat room for each question,

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

This isn't fully thought out yet, so don't get screamy.
[image]
I'm not sure if this is wasteful, but it would be interesting to have the option to "open a chatroom" for each question *right in the page*.

I think it's socially awkward to have to navigate to another page.  It's like going on a camping trip with a friend, but having nothing much to say.  Eh?

So you could just plant a chat room object in the left margin that gets activated when people are commenting too much.

The chat log is saved there, rolled out, in lieu of the lengthy comment stream that sometimes builds up.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47429/guide-people-accessing-closed-questions-to-google-sidewiki

Comment: Are you suggesting persisting the chat log on the question page, after the initial conversation is over? If so, who can see the chat log?

Comment: Note the state of that question, @random, and that bobobobo doesn't have 10k rep.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Well, yes.  In this suggestion the chat log would be public, and serve to clarify the question further.  It'd be possible to delete it if need be. If they choose to delete, then OP edit  clarifications into post.

Comment: Not *tons* different than a (sometimes persistent) comment log.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. I've always seen the chat link as a "stop doing that" rather than a "please continue this here". And I think the former is more desirable than the latter. I don't particularly mind the awkward nature of the current link.

Comment: When chat first came out (on meta) there was an easy way to spawn a room from any question, and they got rid of it. I can't find it now, but somewhere I commented that it was a nice feature they should bring back, and got the reply that they didn't want to overly encourage moving everything to chat

Comment: The real estate is very limited, just from you making those screen shots I can already see that this would not be a nice feature.  It would end up forcing the readers to scroll not only up and down but left and right.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, questions get responses *very* quickly, so quickly that OPs sees this as an opportunity to make follow up questions or help them with other unrelated stuff (it makes them think this site is some kind of *online assistance service*).

Adding a chat will most likely increase this vampirish behavior. Also, it is worth mentioning that there will arise a new risk of losing important details or answers due being posted on the chat instead of comments or answers.

I don't like this idea very much.

Comment: Yeah. I think the possibility (and I'd even say likelihood) of answers being given in chat and not brought back to the site is a great reason to avoid implementing something like this.